# How to convert a 2D Array to a dict in python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, 2d, data-conversion

i got my keys like this

```
"n_1":[], "V_dot_1":[],"dp_ts_1":[],"deta_ts_1":[]
,"n_2":[], "V_dot_2":[],"dp_ts_2":[],"deta_ts_2":[]
,"n_3":[], "V_dot_3":[],"dp_ts_3":[],"deta_ts_3":[]
,"n_4":[], "V_dot_4":[],"dp_ts_4":[],"deta_ts_4":[]
```

and my 2d Array like this

```
1200    500 121.13  0.58076 2400    500 518.14  0.40804 3600    500 1161.23 0.326948    4800    500 2070.93 0.263602
1200    620.6   114.468 0.625004    2400    816.7   492.492 0.534971    3600    1014    1158.03 0.500852    4800    1212.5  2025.75 0.45223
1200    741.1   102.489 0.639035    2400    1133.4  485.683 0.627037    3600    1528.1  1126.73 0.611261    4800    1924.9  2009.99 0.601424
1200    861.7   86.1823 0.625016    2400    1450.1  429.481 0.655226    3600    2042.1  1021.27 0.658989    4800    2637.4  1865.23 0.66133
1200    982.2   66.8493 0.577972    2400    1766.7  345.228 0.638408    3600    2556.2  831.199 0.653071    4800    3349.8  1527.56 0.661191
1200    1102.8  43.6041 0.461404    2400    2083.4  241.121 0.562078    3600    3070.2  590.368 0.588296    4800    4062.3  1093.8  0.601758
1200    1223.3  24.2784 0.306172    2400    2400.1  124.567 0.373738    3600    3584.3  303.16  0.397477    4800    4774.7  562.618 0.411425
1200    1343.96 0.00326267  5.37658e-05 2400    2716.87 0.013187    5.5298e-05  3600    4098.33 0.0298777   5.60525e-05 4800    5487.27 0.0534072   5.66998e-05
```

now i want to create a dict with the upper keys and the values.

It should be look like this.

```
 "n_1":[1200,1200,1200,1200,1200,....], "V_dot_1":[500, 620.6, 741.1, 861.7, ...],"dp_ts_1":[],"deta_ts_1":[]
 ,"n_2":[2400,2400,2400,2400,2400,....], "V_dot_2":[],"dp_ts_2":[],"deta_ts_2":[]
 ,"n_3":[], "V_dot_3":[],"dp_ts_3":[],"deta_ts_3":[]
 ,"n_4":[], "V_dot_4":[],"dp_ts_4":[],"deta_ts_4":[]
```

and so on. is there a Dynamik method to get the columns into the
square brackets. the keys should be the headlines of each column.

Comment: Can you include a sample of your desired output ?

Comment: I edited it. the keys should be the headlines of each column.